# algorithm to calculate activeness in timeslots, given timestamps

Tags: algorithm, timestamp, time-series

Given a series of timestamps of network I/O activities, what's the best algorithm to calculate activeness for all timeslots in a day?

For example, choose slot size =30 seconds, then 1 day = 24*60*60/30 =2880 slots. For one timeslot, label it as **active** or **inactive** based on the timeseries data given (***active*** if there is activity in this slot, ***inactive*** otherwise). Then calculate activeness ratio = (# active slots) / (# total slots).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "best" in this context, but bear with me.

So, we need a function that will take a number of time slots in a 24 hour day, and a timestamp, and return the time slot to which the timestamp belongs. Something like:

```
int GetSlot(int numberOfSlots, int secondsSinceMidnight)
{
    int secondsInSlot = 24 * 60 * 60 / numberOfSlots;
    return secondsSinceMidnight / secondsInSlot;
}
```

Now, create an empty map data structure from time slots to timestamp counts. Start looping through the set of timestamps. For each timestamp, call `GetSlot`; call its slot `assignedSlot`. We check the map data structure to see if it contains an entry for `assignedSlot`. If it does, we increase the mapped counter by one. Otherwise, we add a new entry for `assignedSlot` and set the timestamp count to one. Continue for all timestamps.

At the end, we have one entry in the map data structure for each active slot. We know the total number of slots, so getting the average number of active slots is easy: `map.size() / numberOfSlots`. We've remembered more information than you technically need, but still.

This is O(n) time and O(n) space.

An alternative would be to sort the timestamps in ascending order, then loop over them, counting active time slots as you go. This could be made O(n log n) time and O(1) space.

If you have a bunch of timestamps that are tightly clustered within a few time slots, the first approach will most likely be more efficient. If you have fewer timestamps but they're more evenly distributed throughout time slots, the second approach could be better.

Comment: thanks for mentioning sorting timestamps --definitely an improvement on my map-reduce algo.